# How to test if a unicode character (char32_t) is in upper case in C++

Tags: c++, unicode, char32-t

Is there an `isupper` for `char32_t`? I get an assertion fail on the following code line

> assert(isupper(U'Å'));

Comment: [Locale-aware version](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isupper)

Comment: The older [`isupper()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) in `<ctype.h>`/`<cctype>` is also locale-aware, using the locale set with [`setlocale()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale). But in this case, I would say yes, use the `<clocale>` version instead, and if needed create a custom locale facet that works with UTF-32 data.